# error while installing adt in eclipse

Tags: android, adt

I am installing adt plugin in eclips galileo.but getting below error-

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395    (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be saying that you don't have the Eclipse core runtime where it expects it to be.

An easy way to fix this would be to enable the 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' checkbox on the Install New Software dialog page and that should automatically download all the additional software required for ADT to work.

Otherwise it would be a case of looking through the Eclipse official repository to find and install the runtime.

**Edit:**

Ah, the reason it can't find the 3.6 runtime is that Galileo is 3.5. The new ADT versions will only run on 3.6(Helios) and above.

[ADT Plugin Requirements](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html/)

- Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 20.0.3.

Install Helios or a higher version and it should work fine.

The latest version of Eclipse Classic is Juno, which you can download from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-421/junosr1/).

Comment: 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' checkbox is enabled.But still problem persists.

Comment: @yuva My mistake, didn't realise Galileo was 3.5, you'll have to upgrade your Eclipse to 3.6 or above for ADT to work. I've updated my answer

Comment: how to check version of galileo

Comment: @yuva That wouldn't matter, all Galileo version are 3.5.x, where you need 3.6.0 or higher, which means installed Helios, Indigo or Juno. I've attached a link to the latest version of Eclipse Classic in my answer. Hope this helps you get up and running again!