# Installation of ADT-Plugin fails

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I currently try to install ADT-plugin for Eclipse (Eclipse Helios/CentOS 6.5). After specifying the Download URL

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

I can select the packages to install. Then next step fails with this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
  Missing requirement: Android DDMS 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed? Android-SDK is of course installed...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have Helios *SR2* installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191510/error-while-installing-adt-in-eclipse

Comment: do you have comodo antivirus running?

Comment: Nikka jiha ik jawak: no, this happens with Linux